# JavaScript Array - Filter out values that do not match specific strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to loop through an array and filter out all the items that **do not** match specific values.

For example I have this array:

```
const emails = ["nick@hotmail.com", "nick@yahoo.com", "nick@gmail.com", "bob@yahhoo.com", "bob@gmail.com", "boc@test.com"];
```

I would like to filter out emails that end in"

*@hotmail.com
*@gmail.com

---

I have given it a go and got this but this doesn't work:

```
const filtered = emails.filter((email) => {
  return !email.includes('@hotmail.com') || !email.includes('@gmail.com');
});
```

---

The preferred output from the example above would be:

```
["nick@yahoo.com", "bob@yahhoo.com", "boc@test.com"]
```

Comment: What about `return !(email.endsWith('@hotmail.com') || email.endsWith('@gmail.com'))`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the or `||` with an and `&&`

If you select all emails which do not contain hotmail OR do not contain gmail, you'll get all of them which don't contain both which isn't your objective.
You want to get all of those that do not contain both hotmail and gmail instead!

```
const filtered = emails.filter((email) => {
  return !email.includes('@hotmail.com') && !email.includes('@gmail.com');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Been looking at this for too long, thanks.

Comment: My pleasure :)
If this answers your question, feel free to mark this topic as `Answered`

Comment: Waiting 1 more minute no worries