# What am I doing wrong when filtering out data from a multi-level object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Trying to understand and practice manipulation of passed in data I have created an array of objects:

```
const pizzaObj = [
  {
    id: 'mon',
    name: 'Monday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
  {
    id: 'tues',
    name: 'Tuesday',
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 'small',
        name: 'Small',
      },
      {
        id: 'medium',
        name: 'Medium',
      },
      {
        id: 'large',
        name: 'Large',
      },
      {
        id: 'xlarge',
        name: 'X Large',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'wed',
    name: 'Wednesday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
]
```

that I'm trying to filter out `medium` and `large` from the `subMenu` so it will look like:

```
const pizzaObj = [
  {
    id: 'mon',
    name: 'Monday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
  {
    id: 'tues',
    name: 'Tuesday',
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 'small',
        name: 'Small',
      },
      {
        id: 'xlarge',
        name: 'X Large',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'wed',
    name: 'Wednesday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
]
```

I can remove if just targeting the `subMenu`:

```js
const listToDelete = ['medium', 'large']

const pizzaObj = [
      {
        id: 'small',
        name: 'Small',
      },
      {
        id: 'medium',
        name: 'Medium',
      },
      {
        id: 'large',
        name: 'Large',
      },
      {
        id: 'xlarge',
        name: 'X Large',
      },
    ]

const result = pizzaObj.filter( el => (-1 == listToDelete.indexOf(el.id)) )

console.log(result)
```

But when I try filtering with the object using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) the data isn't removed:

```js
const listToDelete = ['medium', 'large']

const pizzaObj = [
  {
    id: 'mon',
    name: 'Monday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
  {
    id: 'tues',
    name: 'Tuesday',
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 'small',
        name: 'Small',
      },
      {
        id: 'medium',
        name: 'Medium',
      },
      {
        id: 'large',
        name: 'Large',
      },
      {
        id: 'xlarge',
        name: 'X Large',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'wed',
    name: 'Wednesday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
]

const result = pizzaObj.filter(m => {
  return Object.keys(m).some(key => {
    return key === 'subMenu'
      ? m[key].filter(item => -1 === listToDelete.indexOf(item.id))
      : m[key]
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

I've also tried with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const pizzaObj = [
  {
    id: 'mon',
    name: 'Monday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
  {
    id: 'tues',
    name: 'Tuesday',
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 'small',
        name: 'Small',
      },
      {
        id: 'medium',
        name: 'Medium',
      },
      {
        id: 'large',
        name: 'Large',
      },
      {
        id: 'xlarge',
        name: 'X Large',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'wed',
    name: 'Wednesday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
]

const testStrip = data => {
  const listToDelete = ['medium', 'large']
  
return data.filter(m => {
  return Object.keys(m).map(key => {
    return key === 'subMenu'
      ? m[key].filter(item => -1 === listToDelete.indexOf(item.id))
      : m[key]
  })
})
}

console.log(testStrip(pizzaObj))
```

### Research:

- [javascript filter array multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions)
- [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)
- [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)
- [Find and remove objects in an array based on a key value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/find-and-remove-objects-in-an-array-based-on-a-key-value-in-javascript)
- [JavaScript Array - Filter out values that do not match specific strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894523/javascript-array-filter-out-values-that-do-not-match-specific-strings)
- [Replace object value with other object's value of the same key with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041524/replace-object-value-with-other-objects-value-of-the-same-key-with-javascript)

What am I misunderstanding and how should I be filtering out `medium` and `large`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with multiple objects in an array, why not use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over them, and reassign `subMenu` using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as you've already done:

```js
const pizzaObj = [{id: 'mon', name: 'Monday', subMenu: [], }, {id: 'tues', name: 'Tuesday', subMenu: [{id: 'small', name: 'Small', }, {id: 'medium', name: 'Medium', }, {id: 'large', name: 'Large', }, {id: 'xlarge', name: 'X Large', }, ], }, {id: 'wed', name: 'Wednesday', subMenu: [], }, ]

const testStrip = data => {
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.subMenu = d.subMenu.filter(p => !['Medium', 'Large'].includes(p.name))
  });
  return data;
}

console.log(testStrip(pizzaObj))
```

---

Same idea, but with [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which gives some more control if needed:

```js
const pizzaObj = [{id: 'mon', name: 'Monday', subMenu: [], }, {id: 'tues', name: 'Tuesday', subMenu: [{id: 'small', name: 'Small', }, {id: 'medium', name: 'Medium', }, {id: 'large', name: 'Large', }, {id: 'xlarge', name: 'X Large', }, ], }, {id: 'wed', name: 'Wednesday', subMenu: [], }, ]

const testStrip = data => (
    data.reduce((prev, cur) => [
        ...prev,
        { 
            ...cur, 
            subMenu: cur.subMenu = cur.subMenu.filter(p => !['Medium', 'Large'].includes(p.name))
        }
    ], [])
)

console.log(testStrip(pizzaObj))
```

Comment: I thought about `forEach` but I wasn't finding any conclusive data if that would be a strain on performance if `data` was large such as an API request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const filterData = (data, exclude) => 
  data.map(d => ({
   ...d,
   subMenu: d.subMenu.filter(({id}) => !exclude.includes(id))
  }))



const listToDelete = ['medium', 'large']


const pizzaObj = [
  {
    id: 'mon',
    name: 'Monday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
  {
    id: 'tues',
    name: 'Tuesday',
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 'small',
        name: 'Small',
      },
      {
        id: 'medium',
        name: 'Medium',
      },
      {
        id: 'large',
        name: 'Large',
      },
      {
        id: 'xlarge',
        name: 'X Large',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'wed',
    name: 'Wednesday',
    subMenu: [],
  },
]

console.log(filterData(pizzaObj, listToDelete))
```